# Change stdout/stderr output device

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, file-descriptors, exec

By default if we run

```
foo(){
  echo "myfoo"
}
```

it will go to stdout. My question is, for a bash script or function, is there a programmatic way to change the device so that commands don't automatically write to stdout?

maybe something like this:

```
foo(){
  mkfifo bar
  exec 1<>bar
  echo "myfoo"  # this gets written to the bar named pipe?
}
```

so we "repoint" stdout somewhere else perhaps?

Comment: yeah that doesn't seem to work. If i run `tail -f bar` I don't seem to get any data there.

Comment: Are you asking for something very different from `foo >bar`?

Comment: @Kusalananda honestly, I might delete this question, this new question is better: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442461/using-process-substitution-only-send-stderr-to-process

Answer (score 0):

This technique will probably do the trick:
[Using process substitution, only send stderr to process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442461/using-process-substitution-only-send-stderr-to-process)

Basically, you call:

```
exec > $some_file
```

using process substitution, you can do something like:

```
exec > >( while read line; do echo " stdout: $line"; done )
```

that means that all stdout will go to that file instead of to the terminal.