# Using process substitution, only send stderr to process

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, process-substitution

I have this:

```
exec > >( while read line; do echo " stdout: $line"; done )
exec 2> >( while read line; do echo " stderr: $line"; done )

echo "rolo"
>&2 echo "cholo"
```

if you run that script, it results in the following output:

> stdout: rolo
>      stdout: stderr: cholo

how can I only send stderr to the second process substitution line?
I don't get it.

I don't understand why this is happening:

> stdout: rolo
>   stdout: stderr: cholo  # what lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set up the redirections in the wrong order.  The standard output of the second process substitution (which prefixes with `stderr:`) has its standard output prefixed by the first process substitution, because it was run afterwards.

Try this instead:

```
exec 2> >( while read line; do echo " stderr: $line"; done )
exec > >( while read line; do echo " stdout: $line"; done )

echo "rolo"
echo "cholo" >&2
```

This outputs

```
 stderr: cholo
 stdout: rolo
```

which is what I presume you want.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77202/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-using-process-substitution-only-send-stderr).